# Portable event checker with condition and lock-free notification

Tags: c++, events, lock-free, condition-variable

I need to let a realtime (audio) thread signal another background thread when an event happens. The background "checker" thread will then perform some expensive operation.

Therefore my restrictions are:

- The notification operation must be lock-free (no such restriction on the wait side)
- Prevent the checker thread from wasting CPU time and put it to sleep properly when it's not needed instead, considering that events might be up to minutes apart from each other.
- The code must be portable (osx, windows, android, ios).

I came up with a simple solution using a condition variable and a condition flag. The flag is needed to prevent the checker thread to wait (potentially forever) when the condition variable is signaled before the checker thread starts waiting.

```
struct EventChecker {

    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<bool> flag;
    bool alive;
    std::thread checkerThread;

    EventChecker() {
        alive = true;
        checkerThread = std::thread([this]() {
            while (alive) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return flag.exchange(false); });
                std::cout << " action! ";
            }
        });
    }

    void notify() {
        flag.store(true);
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    ~EventChecker() {
        alive = false;
        notify();
        checkerThread.join();
    }
};
```

This solution will deadlock (precisely, the checker thread is not waken up) if `notify()` happens between the flag check and the actual start of the wait. That's more clear if you think that the implementation of `wait` with condition is just:

```
while (!predicate())
    wait(lock);
```

And with this simple test it's quite easy to get the deadlock (reproduced on a macbook):

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            EventChecker ec;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, there's actually no way to make the check+wait operation atomic without locking `mtx` inside notify, and adding an unlock on the wait side to reduce the retention time, like this:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return flag.exchange(false); });
// NB: wait() atomically releases lock and blocks the thread
mtx.unlock();
```

Am I missing something? Am I misusing `std::condition_variable` and there's something else more suitable for my purpose?

Comment: One way to "fix" the issue is to allow the checker thread to wake up regularly using `wait_for(...)`. Might be a good enough compromise if I don't find anything better, and I decide I can accept a few milliseconds of delay in handling the event.

Comment: Why not just fire up a new thread when you have work for it to do? If you only have *some* work once in a while and there's a high risk of the thread having nothing to do, I think that would be the better option.

Comment: Firing a thread is an expensive operation and likely to allocate memory on the heap, which is something to avoid on the realtime audio thread.

Comment: I am currently looking at semaphores, carefully reading https://preshing.com/20150316/semaphores-are-surprisingly-versatile/ hoping I can use something from there!

Comment: Then perhaps, busy waiting is really the only option.

Answer (score 1):

For atomic *check-and-wait* without locks you may use *futex* mechanism. Unfortunately, this mechanism is not part of any C/C++ standard, it is part of the low-level OS support:

- Linux (and Android too) has [futex](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) syscall.
- Windows has [WaitOnAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/hh706898(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

I haven't found any analogue of futex on OSX, and unaware of its on ios.

Comment: Interesting, I would need to find something for mac os and ios, though. Apparently futexes are not part of posix, are they?

Comment: No, POSIX doesn't contain futexes.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a couple of possible solutions, that require accepting some compromises that might be acceptable depending on the situation, and did some measurements during the weekend because I love having fun.

I have rewritten the `EventChecker` to work with three possible implementations of an `Event` class:

- `Event_WithStdMutex`: a reference "canonical" implementation using `std::mutex`
- `Event_WithLightLock`: which still protects the condition with a mutex, but a lightweight one (a spin-lock, precisely). The idea here is that when the event occurrence is relatively rare, the checker thread will almost always already be sitting on the wait when the notify occurs, so the acquisition of the lock by the notifying thread will have almost no overhead.
- `Event_WithTimeout`: where the notification is not protected by the lock, but we use `wait_for` to let the checker thread wake up in the worst case (as described in the question). This would be used when we need the notify to be fast at all costs and we can afford having the event be handled with a delay equal to the `wait_for` timeout in the worst case. The timeout time  choice would be a trade-off between worst-case responsiveness and CPU time saving.

Here the implementations:

```
struct Event_WithStdMutex {
    std::condition_variable_any cv;
    std::atomic<bool> condition;
    std::mutex mtx;

    Event_WithStdMutex() : condition(false) {}

    void wait() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return condition.exchange(false); });
    }

    void notify() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        condition.store(true);
        cv.notify_one();
    }
};

struct LightMutex {
    std::atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
    void lock() { while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)); }
    void unlock() { flag.clear(std::memory_order_release); }
};

struct Event_WithLightLock {
    std::condition_variable_any cv;
    std::atomic<bool> condition;
    LightMutex mtx;

    Event_WithLightLock() : condition(false) {}

    void wait() {
        std::unique_lock<LightMutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return condition.exchange(false); });
    }

    void notify() {
        std::unique_lock<LightMutex> lock(mtx);
        condition.store(true);
        cv.notify_one();
    }
};


struct Event_WithTimeout {
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<bool> condition;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::chrono::milliseconds timeout;

    Event_WithTimeout() : condition(false), timeout(10) {}

    void wait() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait_for(lock, timeout, [this]() { return condition.exchange(false); });
    }

    void notify() {
        condition.store(true);
        cv.notify_one();
    }
};
```

And the event checker (note the 1 microsecond sleep to "simulate" some kind of operation):

```
template <typename Event> struct EventChecker {

    bool alive;
    std::thread checkerThread;
    Event event;

    EventChecker() {
        alive = true;
        checkerThread = std::thread([this]() {
            while (alive) {
                event.wait();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1)); // comment this for more fun
            }
        });
    }

    void notify() {
        event.notify();
    }

    ~EventChecker() {
        alive = false;
        notify();
        checkerThread.join();
    }
};
```

Following is the function I used for the measurements. The duration of `notify()` is measured both in the context of the `EventChecker` (with a thread waiting for events), and with just the Event (to measure the time when no-one is waiting on the condition variable):

```
const int N = 1000000;

template <typename Event> void measureNotify(std::string eventType) {

    EventChecker<Event> evChecker;
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        evChecker.notify();
    }
    auto dur = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - begin;
    std::cout << "EventChecker (with " << eventType << ") avg notify time: "
        << std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(dur).count() / N << " ns \n";

    Event ev;
    begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ev.notify();
    }
    dur = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - begin;
    std::cout << eventType << " avg notify time (no-one waiting): "
        << std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(dur).count() / N << " ns \n\n";
}
```

And also a measurement of the time taken by `std::condition_variable`'s `notify_one()`, with no-one waiting on it:

```
void measureNotifyConditionVariable()
{
    std::condition_variable cv;
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cv.notify_one();
    }
    auto dur = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - begin;
    std::cout << "std::condition_variable avg notify time (no-one waiting): "
        << std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(dur).count() / N << " ns \n";
}
```

Running the tests on a macbook pro (2.2GHz) yelds these results:

> EventChecker (with Event_WithStdMutex) avg notify time: 157.522 ns
>
> Event_WithStdMutex avg notify time (no-one waiting): 67.3699 ns
>
> EventChecker (with Event_WithLightLock) avg notify time: 67.1347 ns
>
> Event_WithLightLock avg notify time (no-one waiting): 61.0349 ns
>
> EventChecker (with Event_WithTimeout) avg notify time: 23.5722 ns
>
> Event_WithTimeout avg notify time (no-one waiting): 22.3806 ns
>
> std::condition_variable avg notify time (no-one waiting): 13.6012 ns

Interestingly, this is the output when the 1-microsecond sleep is removed:

> EventChecker (with Event_WithStdMutex) avg notify time: 7346.42 ns
>
> Event_WithStdMutex avg notify time (no-one waiting): 66.202 ns
>
> EventChecker (with Event_WithLightLock) avg notify time: 337.239 ns
>
> Event_WithLightLock avg notify time (no-one waiting): 61.8729 ns
>
> EventChecker (with Event_WithTimeout) avg notify time: 46.7398 ns
>
> Event_WithTimeout avg notify time (no-one waiting): 22.2315 ns
>
> std::condition_variable avg notify time (no-one waiting): 13.3488 ns

The average `notify()` duration becomes higher when there's someone waiting on the condition variable (incredibly higher in the `std::mutex` case!).

My understanding is that this happens because it's more likely for the notifying thread to actually have to contend the waiting thread for the lock.